# Replacing string assignment by PChar operation

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a puzzling result that I'm struggling to understand.

I've been attempting to improve the speed of this routine

```
function TStringRecord.GetWord: String;
begin
  // return the next word in Input
  Result := '';

  while (PC^ <> #$00) and not PC^.IsLetter do begin
    inc(FPC);
  end;

  while (PC^ <> #$00) and PC^.IsLetter do begin
    Result := Result + PC^;
    inc(FPC);
  end;
end;
```

by replacing the `Result := Result + PC^` by a pointer-based operation.  This
is my attempt:

```
function TStringRecord.GetWord2: String;
var
  Len : Integer;
  StartPC,
  DestPC : PChar;
begin
  // return the next word in Input
  Result := '';

  while (PC^ <> #$00) and not PC^.IsLetter do begin
    inc(FPC);
  end;

  Len := Length(Input);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  StartPC := PChar(Result);
  DestPC := PChar(Result);
  while (PC^ <> #$00) and PC^.IsLetter do begin
    WStrPLCopy(DestPC, PC, 1);
    inc(FPC);
    inc(DestPC);
  end;
  SetLength(Result, DestPC - StartPC);
end;
```

According to my line profiler, `WStrPLCopy(DestPC, PC, 1)` takes 50 times longer
than `Result := Result + PC^`.  As far as I can tell, this is because on entry
to WStrPLCopy there is a call to `_WStrFromPWChar` which seems to copy many more
characters than the one necessary.  How can I avoid this, or can someone suggest
an alternative PChar-based method?

The remainder of my code is below:

```
TStringRecord = record
private
  FPC: PChar;
  FInput: String;
  procedure SetInput(const Value: String);
public
  function NextWord : String;
  function NextWord2 : String;
  property Input : String read FInput write SetInput;
  property PC : PChar read FPC;
end;

procedure TStringRecord.SetInput(const Value: String);
begin
  FInput := Value;
  FPC := PChar(Input);
end;
```

Comment: Without you showing us meaningful code, it's hard to help. You've omitted any reference to the input string. You are performing two heap allocations when one will suffice. You are copying piecemeal. Surely you need to find the start and end index, and use `Copy`. I assure you that you will get better answers if you show your code.

Comment: I wasn't intending to conceal anything, just wanting to omit irrelevant detail.  Input may typically be several k of characters.  What am I copying "piecemeal" as you put it, and what do you have in mind by two heap allocations?

Comment: You perform two heap allocations. They are as plain as can be in the code. You only need to do one. Rather than copying character by character, I'd copy once at the end. I'd not use `PChar` here and instead would use indices. I would be very wary of line profilers. Use a stopwatch to time this.

Comment: Anyway, I'm reluctant to write any code because there's still a lot of missing information. We don't know typical input data, how the code fits in with the rest of your program, and so on.

Comment: "how the code fits in " Oh, this is just a self-instructional exercise, typical input is anything, really.  Anyway I wasn't intending to ask for any code. I changed my code to do roughly what you suggested (copy only after finding the end) and it works fine and is comparable with the GetWord method, speed-wise, so thanks.  Not sure what about my q deserved a -1, but that's the joy of SO, I guess.  I'm still curious about what the call to `_WStrFromPWChar` is about but I think I'll ask about that separately so as not to get bogged down with disapproval of my code.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would write it:

```
function TStringRecord.GetWord: String;
var beg: PChar;
begin
  // return the next word in Input
  while (FPC^ <> #0) and not FPC^.IsLetter do 
    inc(FPC);
  beg := FPC;
  while (FPC^ <> #0) and FPC^.IsLetter do 
    inc(FPC);
  SetString(result, beg, FPC-beg);
end;
```

With this, code is very readable, and you have a single memory allocation, and I guess you could not write anything faster (but by inlining `PC^.IsLetter`, which is the only call to an external piece of code).

Comment: Assume first call, returns only eventual space(s) in the beginning of `Input` (**not** PC^.IsLetter). If you fix that, you would still need to advance past spaces(s) between words before setting `beg`

Comment: @TomBrunberg You are right: I did not follow exactly the search algorithm  used - just wanted to show how to code some string extraction using PChar variables, with a single memory allocation.

Comment: Isn't indexing using `[]` faster than pointer arithmetic based approaches?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Both compiles to the same asm, but when you use @astring[20] which calls UniqueString() AFAIR. And in the context of this OP, the input is using PChar, so my answer use PChar. Of course, regular Delphi code may use some index + copy(), with the same performance.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I think that the original code is using pointers because the asker thinks they are faster. And if they aren't, then that should not constraint us. `[]` will only force a unique string when modifying the string.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OR when you write @astring[20]  to retrieve a pointer to a character AFAIR, even if you don't plan to modify its content. In some cases, a pointer may be slightly faster than an indexed string access, since it would avoid the use of two registers for each access: it *may* generates better code, especially if your function is short, and has the pointer as one of its input parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I arrived at virtually the same code following @DavidHeffernan's suggestion in comments.  David: I didn't have an opinion about whether pointers or indexed strings were faster, this was just to find out how to do it with pointers, like I said, self-instruction.

Comment: @AlexA The point here was that if you use `PChar`, the easiest to create a string from a `PChar` buffer is with `SetString()`, which is a not-very-known low-level function.